# Invoke oracle stored procedure from shell script without SQLPLUS

Tags: oracle, shell, unix, stored-procedures, autosys

Can anyone please suggest a way to invoke an Oracle stored procedure from a shell script without the use of SQL*Plus, or any such client for that matter. The inability to install clients is a limitation of the server that I work on.

I have to schedule an Autosys script to invoke the job which invokes the Oracle stored procedure. Can you please suggest in what direction should I proceed?

Comment: Java and jdbc have been suggested by @ik_zelf.  Similarly, if you have Perl, Ruby, Python or similar scripting languages with a built-in database facility you may be able to get to your database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this using Java and jdbc. If you can not even copy the thin jdbc driver, I see no other option than to schedule the job in Oracle Using Oracle Scheduler.

Comment: Thanks. I think I Oracle scheduler seems the only option for me.

Answer (score 0):

Without client software installed, you'll have a hard time getting to Oracle from a shell script; however, Oracle has it's own batch facility--see Database jobs [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/schedover004.htm#autoId4)